# Highlighting a row in asp.net gridview on click of template button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I hav an asp.net grid view that i have structured like this..

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridContractor" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="GridViewStyle" GridLines="None" EnableModelValidation="True"
                DataKeyNames="DeviceID" OnRowCommand="gridContractor_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="gridContractor_PageIndexChanging"
                Width="100%" EmptyDataText = "No records to display">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Device IMEI" DataField="DeviceID" Visible="false">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="175" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Person Name" DataField="PersonName">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="#Observations" DataField="GpsPointsCount" ControlStyle-Width="50px">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="50" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="#Violations" DataField="ViolationCount" ControlStyle-Width="60px">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="60" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="50">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="View" Enabled="true"
                                CommandArgument="<%#Bind('DeviceID') %>" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle Width="50" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
                <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />
                <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
                <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
                <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

even though i have specified the `<SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle">` which is an external Css i am not able to see changes in the selected row background color

i aslo tried doing this `<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="AliceBlue" />` and still no changes
can some body tell me why this is not working?

Comment: Could you please post the CSS as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted you are nowhere selecting a row. You have to do it if you want the `SelectedRowStyle` to be applied.

There are several ways you can select a row :

- Using a button/image/link with `CommandName="Select"`
- Handle it manually by setting the grid view `SelectedIndex` from code behind.

For example in your row command handler `gridContractor_RowCommand` you can write :

```
protected void gridContractor_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    [...]
    GridViewRow selectedRow = (GridViewRow((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
    int intRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow.RowIndex);
    gridContractor.SelectedIndex = intRowIndex 
    [...]
}
```